# Access violation at adress... Что делать?

Tags: delphi

```
...
type   Tbgra = record
       b,g,r,a:byte;
       end;
var    temp:array of array of tbgra;
       x:integer;
begin

  // round(k*setedbrush.w) = 150, round(setedbrush.h*k)=150

  setlength(temp, round(k*setedbrush.w)+1);

  for x:=1 to round(k*setedbrush.w) do
     setlength(temp,  round(setedbrush.h*k)+1);

  temp[1,1].r:=6;  //Access violation at adress...
 ...
```

Кстати, в процедуре, из которой этот участок кода, очень много переменных (в т.ч. и массивов). Может быть из-за этого?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы допустили грубейшую ошибку новичка вот здесь:

```
for x:=1 to round(k*setedbrush.w) do
     setlength(temp,  round(setedbrush.h*k)+1);
```

Получается, что вы пересоздаете один и тот-же массив "temp", а надо указывать его индекс( чтобы вы создавали в цикле его второе измерение, а не сто раз его самого).

Надо так:

```
    ...
type   Tbgra = record
       b,g,r,a:byte;
       end;
var    temp:array of array of tbgra;
       x:integer;
begin

  // round(k*setedbrush.w) = 150, round(setedbrush.h*k)=150

  setlength(temp, round(k*setedbrush.w)+1);

  for x:=1 to round(k*setedbrush.w) do
     setlength(temp[x],  round(setedbrush.h*k)+1);

  temp[1,1].r:=6;
```

Comment: Миллион раз перепроыерил, а вот такую фигульку не заметил. Как же мне теперь стыдно)). Наверно к вечеру мозги соображать перестали)...

Comment: Да уж, такое бывает у всех, поверьте =)